# Minimizing $|\frac{f'}{f}|$ and $|\frac{f''}{f}|$ under constraints.

Tags: derivatives, inequality, boundary-value-problem

Let's give constraints first.

$f$ is a $C^2$ function on $[0,K]$, and we require that $f(0)=f(K)=1$, $f'(0)=C$, $C>0$ is a given constant. The goal is to minimize the quantities $$\left|\frac{f'}{f}\right|$$ and $$\left|\frac{f''}{f}\right|.$$

Here, the absolute value means the uniform norm on the interval $[0,K].$

I wonder if there's an obstruction to minimize them, like having an lower of bound of them in terms of $C,K$. Otherwise, we would be able to minimize them as much as we want.

Or, are there any useful integral inequalities related to this? Or, any deep theory explaining it, like calculus of variations? If so, please guide me to references.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first can't be smaller than $|\frac{C}{1}|$.  The 2nd term must be some value large enough to get the function back down to $f(K)=1$ after starting with a positive slope.   The slope in the middle should be $f'(K/2)=0$ and $f'(K)=-C$.

Comment: I think one of the unstated constraints is that the function is continuous and had continuous 1st and 2nd derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

Set the value of $|\frac{f''}f|$ to a constant Q.  Then put $f$ on the other side:

$$f'' = Q f$$  From this it is relatively obvious that $e^x$ will come in to play.  With that and the other constraints you can find the exact function.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Should have been a shifted/ scaled hyperbolic cosine.  I didn't figure out how to invert things the exact constant for scaling.  Could be done numerically with specific values for C,K.